# UIDatePicker doesn't recognise that it currently shows the current date

Tags: swift, uidatepicker

My swift app uses a UIDatePicker for the user to select a date. However, I want to set it up so that it displays "No date inserted" for when the user forgets to insert it.

The problem is that when I set up an `if` statement that displays the warning based on whether the datePicker's date is equal to the current date, it simply doesn't recognise it at all. Here's my code:

```
if datePicker.date == NSDate() {
    warnL.text = "NO DATE INSERTED"
}
```

What could I do about it?
Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an easier way to know if a date is today is to use a method on `NSCalendar`:

```
if NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDateInToday(datePicker.date) {
    warnL.text = "NO DATE INSERTED"
}
```

Which takes care of the timezone, locale and type of calendar.

Answer (score 0):

`NSDate` return all date, including time, so it will never be equal to time in Your `datePicker`.
You can define variable which tell You if date was changed:

```
var dateWasChanged = false
```

And then You can register handler for change event:

```
func viewDidLoad() {
   datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(YourViewController.handleDatePicker), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
}

func handleDatePicker() {
    dateWasChanged = true
}
```

After that You can check if `dateWasChanged` is `true` and show Your information.

Comment: Oh ok, now I understand why it didn't work! However, after closely following the steps mentioned above, I still get an error: 'Type 'ViewController' has no member 'handleDatePicker.' How could I make it a member of the ViewController or simply make it work?

Comment: Here's the code to it: 'var dateWasChanged = false
        datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.handleDatePicker), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
        func handleDatePicker() {
            dateWasChanged = true
        }
'

Comment: You need to put `var dateWasChanged = false` as Your ViewControllers variable, then call `addTarget` method in `viewDidLoad`. And `handleDatePicker` put as method in Your ViewController.